# Django,IIS. I can't publish django using IIS

Tags: python, django, iis

I'm trying to publish django using Microsoft IIS. I got an error when accessing http://localhost. Django version is 3.1.7 and python is 3.9.2, windows server 2019.

Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler
    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 603, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = getattr(handler, name)
AttributeError: module 'django.core' has no attribute 'wsgi'
```

StdOut:

StdErr:

Comment: There are empty values in the StdOut & StdErr. Please update your question details.

Comment: Thanks. When I access http://localhost, I get the above message. StdOut: and StdErr: are empty.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for this error, you can try below methods to solve this error:

1. In your Django project, there is a **init**.py file, remove it and try again.
2. Try to find your Python folder (C:\python27 by default) and forcibly reset the permissions, i.e. Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object as shown here: https://serverfault.com/questions/475612/replace-permission-entries-on-all-child-objects-using-icacls

If the problem cannot be solved, please share your project path and Web.config file.